# Creating a custom exception class

Tags: java, class, exception

I am new to Java programing and I am trying to create a custom exception class that extends exception.  The UML class diagram I was given is:

UnluckyNumberException

unluckyNumber: int

UnluckyNumberException(int)
getUnluckyNumber():int

1) Class needs to extend class exception, which I assume is:
public class UnluckyNumberException extends Exception

2) Its constructor should accept as an argument the "unlucky number" that the exception represents.  This value should be stored as an instance variable in the object (as an int)
*** Need help here ***

3) You will need to implement method getUnluckyNumber, which gets called in main.  This merely returns the "unlucky number" stored in the object
*** Need help here ***

Here is the call in main:

catch (UnluckyNumberException e)
{
  System.out.printf ("Error: you entered an unlucky number: %d\n", e.getUnluckyNumber());
}

Comment: What specifically don't you understand from the requirements?  Why are points 2 & 3 giving your trouble?  Have you gone back over your course notes? Have you read through [Providing Constructors for Your Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) and [Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)? What else have you tried?

Comment: Look at [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) and especially the section on "Creating exception classes".

Comment: Pretty simple. Look over your notes.

Answer (score 0):

Excetion:

```
public class UnluckyNumberException extends RuntimeException {
    private final int unluckyNumber;

    public UnluckyNumberException(int unluckyNumber) {
        this.unluckyNumber = unluckyNumber;
    }

    public int getUnluckyNumber() {
        return unluckyNumber;
    }

}
```

main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ...
            throw new UnluckyNumberException(3);
        ...
    } catch (UnluckyNumberException e) {
        System.out.printf ("Error: you entered an unlucky number: %d\n", e.getUnluckyNumber());
    }
}
```